# Cookie value not persisting across methods; I set the value in one method but in the next method that calls it is has no value (C#)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, cookies

I'm using javascript to set the value of a cookie when I open the debugger panel so that if the user has already opened it, it will automatically open when they reload the page.

Here is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    DebuggingPanel.init(jQuery);
    DebuggingPanel.GetPanelState();
});

DebuggingPanel.GetPanelState = function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/sitecore modules/DebuggingPanel/DebuggingPanel.asmx/GetPanelState",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.open === true) {
                DebuggingPanel.TogglePanel();
            }
        }
    });
}

DebuggingPanel.TogglePanel = function (changeState) {

    var tinyDiv = $('.debuggingPanel.tinyDiv');

    if (tinyDiv.text() == '+') {

        tinyDiv.text('-');
        DebuggingPanel.GetInformation();
        DebuggingPanel.panel.slideDown();

        interval = setInterval(DebuggingPanel.GetInformation, 5000);

        if (changeState) {
            DebuggingPanel.SetPanelState("open");
        }

    } else {

        tinyDiv.text('+');
        DebuggingPanel.panel.slideUp();

        clearInterval(interval);

        if (changeState) {
            DebuggingPanel.SetPanelState("closed");
        }
    }        
};

tinyDiv.click(function () {
    DebuggingPanel.TogglePanel(true);
});
```

And here are the methods related to the cookie:

```
public void SetPanelState(string state)
{
    var panelCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["PanelState"];
    if (panelCookie == null)
    {
        panelCookie = new HttpCookie("PanelState") {Value = state};
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(panelCookie);
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["PanelState"].Value = state;
    }
}

[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json), WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void GetPanelState()
{
    var panelCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["PanelState"];
    var data = new PanelState(){open = false};
    if (panelCookie == null || panelCookie.Value == null)
    {
        data.open = false;
    }
    else if (panelCookie.Value == "open")
    {
        data.open = true;
    }
    WriteOut(data);
}
```

In debugging the cookie looks as though it is getting the value correctly, but the next time I go into `GetPanelState()`, `panelCookie.Value` is always `""` (not `"open"` as it should be, or `"closed"`, which would indicate it was set by the toggle).

This happens when I reload the page, and it also happens when I call `GetPanelState()` at the end of `SetPanelState()`; `panelCookie.Value = "open"` in `SetPanelState()` but then equals `""` in `GetPanelState()`

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading from the Cookie, you need to use the `Request` instead of the response. So your code will be as follows:

```
public void SetPanelState(string state)
{
  var panelCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["PanelState"];
  if (panelCookie == null)
  {
      panelCookie = new HttpCookie("PanelState") {Value = state};
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(panelCookie);
  }
  else
  {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["PanelState"].Value = state;
  }
}

[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json), WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void GetPanelState()
{
   //It is here that you are reading the cookie.
   var panelCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["PanelState"];
   var data = new PanelState(){open = false};
   if (panelCookie == null || panelCookie.Value == null)
   {
      data.open = false;
   }
   else if (panelCookie.Value == "open")
   {
      data.open = true;
   }

   WriteOut(data);
}
```

Thanks